# Android LinkedHashMap.eldest() method is NOT available

Tags: android, linkedhashmap

I see the LinkedHashMap.eldest() method when attaching the source but cannot use it.

Any idea why it isn't available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a hidden method - invokable using reflection, but isn't part of the public API and therefore likely to change between versions of android

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a47f800/luni/src/main/java/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java line 169 the @hide annotation stops it from being visible to the public

Answer (score 0):

Because there no such method in this class and any super type:

[LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

[HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

[AbstractMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/AbstractMap.html)